# Issue with JPA Controller Generation in NetBeans: Missing Methods and Constructors

Tags: java, jpa, netbeans

I am currently facing an issue while attempting to create a JPA controller for a class entity in NetBeans. When I generate the controller, none of the expected methods or constructors are being created – everything appears empty. Contrary to my experience, I've observed in video tutorials that others receive controllers with their respective constructors and methods pre-populated.

Has anyone encountered a similar problem or has insights into why this might be happening? Are there specific configurations or steps I might be missing during the controller generation process in NetBeans? Any guidance on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

In the end I had to manually create the builders and methods, but I want to know how I can use Netbeans to automatically give them to me

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.